# Why redux store is cleared when move to backgorund?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

i'm trying to use redux in expo(react-native).
When i move to background, the redux state is cleared.
I don't know how to prevent it
please help~!~!

[image: Normal state]

[image: When i move to background]